# WSDL PolicyReference to an external file

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf, policy

I'm getting some errors when I try to deploy a web service generated using CXF's wsdl2java to generate the Java code from a WSDL file.  I've managed to trace the error down to a NullPointerException being thrown by Apache Neethi when I tries to normalize a PolicyReference.  The policy reference is defined in an external XML file (a lot of WSDLs reference this policy file).  Here is what I see in the WSDL:

```
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="policy:someExternalFile.xml#PolicyName" />
```

I've tried removing the "policy:" scheme at the start of URI and getting rid of the URI scheme all together.

If I move the policy into the WSDL, things work fine.  I'm using CXF 2.2.3 and Tomcat 6.  The version of Apache Neethi that is included with this release is 2.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you can log a bug with CXF and attach a sample wsdl/policy that shows the issue?  It MAY be a neethi issue bug it could also be a bug in the CXF policy loading mechanisms.  Having a test case is quite useful for diagnosing this.